# List of sins punishable by excision or death

Tags: capital-punishment, karet

Where please can I find a list of the sins punishable by korais (excision) and those punishable by death?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See Rambam [Sanhedrin 15](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e115.htm):10-13 for those obligated in the court-imposed death penalties and [ibid 19](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e119.htm):1-3 for those obligated in Karet or Mitah Bidei Shamayim.

Comment: I think the first Mishna of Kerisus also has it

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved if you would have the actual list in the answer (perhaps both in Hebrew and English...)